# I cannot change Game Centre Profile name

Tags: ios

When I first put in my nickname I used emoji with the name. now each time I try to sign in to change the name a box comes up saying to update my account cannot connect to server. As far as I know my account is updated. However the emoji keyboard no longer is available when I sign in. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you try to login?

Answer (score 2):

To log in to Game Center, you use your Apple ID email and password, not your Game Center nickname. Go to Settings > Game Center, tap your current nickname (under Game Center Profile) and then you should be able to edit it.

Comment: I always sign in with Apple ID and password as I didn't know you could have a different one for game centre.